# Why does Perl's Net::SFTP->new complain about "Not an ARRAY reference"?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to use Net::SFTP to get connected to remote server.

My script is:

```
my %args = ( 
    ssh_args => { 
       user => 'canneu_scp', 
       identity_files => [ '/home/home1/cgrshah/responsys/capgemini.private' ], 
       debug => 1, 
 } );

my $targetserver='files.responsys.net';

my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($targetserver, %args) 
      or die "could not open connection to $targetserver\n";
```

But when I run this, I get an error stating:

```
 Not an ARRAY reference at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.1/Net/SFTP.pm line 36.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you post the code surrounding line 36 in your version of `Net::SFTP` or maybe just post which version you are using?

Comment: Always post complete example scripts so we can see everything that you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a wild shot in the dark, but the `user` option should not be in the hash handed to `ssh_args`, it is at the same level.  Try using this code instead:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new(
    $targetserver,
    user     => 'canneu_scp', 
    ssh_args => { 
        identity_files => [ '/home/home1/cgrshah/responsys/capgemini.private' ], 
        debug => 1,
    } 
) or die "could not open connection to $targetserver\n";
```

It sounds like the code above got you further along, and now you are having problems because your version of [`Math::BigInt`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-BigInt/lib/Math/BigInt.pm) is too old.  I see three ways to move forward:

1. switch to an RSA key instead of a DSA key
2. find an RPM of `Math::BigInt` version 1.78 or later
3. manually install a copy of `Math::BigInt`

The third option has many pitfalls, and if you decide to go with it I would suggest the following steps:

1. install [`App::cpanminus`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus.pm)

   1. make sure you have a gcc installed
   2. run `wget -O- http://cpanmin.us | perl - --local-lib=~/perl5 App::cpanminus`
   3. add `~/perl5/bin` to your path
2. install `Math::BigInt` into your home directory with `cpanm --local-lib=~/perl5 Math::BigInt`
3. add `use lib "$ENV{HOME}/perl5";` to the start of your script so it can find the new modules

Comment: yep see http://search.cpan.org/~dbrobins/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm#Net::SFTP-%3Enew%28$host,_%args%29

Comment: I look in the source code of the module and it seems there on line 36 like $sftp is not an ARRAY REF

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DBROBINS/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm

Comment: @Berov That is the latest version, we don't know what version he or she is using.  In version 0.10, there is nothing being used as an arrayref near line 36, so I am assuming that he or she is using an earlier version of a version that has been modified.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply.
@Chas. Owens, I tried the code which you suggested.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, I tried the code you gave:
I am getting the foll error:
Key class 'Net::SSH::Perl::Key::DSA' is unsupported: Math::BigInt version 1.78 required--this is only version 1.70 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/Crypt/DSA/KeyChain.pm line 4, <GEN0> line 1.

Comment: versions I am using are:
perl-Net-SFTP-0.10-1.el4.rf, 
perl-Net-SSH-Perl-1.34-1.el4.rf, 
perl-Math-Pari-2.01080603-1.el4.rf, 
perl-Math-GMP-2.05-1.el4.rf. 

Can anyone help in how to get rid of this error??

Comment: hi Chas...i am the same user who asked this question.
Was not able to access my account so created a new one.

Actually I am still stuck up in the same problem of Math::BigInt.
Can you explain me how to exactly go for option 1:
1. switch to an RSA key instead of a DSA key